Populate an Excel file from SharePoint list items

I want to ask how to create a flow where it extracts the data from a SharePoint list to populate an Excel file. The SharePoint List is an expense claim submitted and approved by employees and managers. I need to populate 2 Excel files for our finance department. I have attached the Excel File. This SharePoint list items are created on PowerApps Form, so if any data manipulation is needed, I can try to make it on PowerApps before creating it on SharePoint List. Thanks!
Populate an Excel file from SharePoint list items

There are many tutorials and templates available for this. What have you tried? Present a more focused question/problem.

And can you also specify which Excel format you are looking to have as an output, .csv or  .xlsx
